# Adding a line below TabLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-tablayout, tabbar

I'm having a trouble trying to add a line below the `TabLayout`, but it has to be behind the selector line. Should be something like this:

[image: Exemple]

I already tried to add a custom view, but each tab have some margin inside, so didn't worked out.

any ideas?

This is what I got right now:

[image: current_tablayout]

Here its how i'm adding it on XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:tabBackground="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"/>
```

and this is what i'm doing via code:

```
private void configureTabLayout() {
    TabLayout.Tab tabHome = mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_cinza);
    TabLayout.Tab tabEmprestimos = mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_emprestimos_cinza);
    TabLayout.Tab tabPersonal = mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_usuario_cinza);

    View root = mTabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    if (root instanceof LinearLayout) {
        ((LinearLayout) root).setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silver));
        drawable.setSize(2, 1);
        ((LinearLayout) root).setDividerPadding(10);
        ((LinearLayout) root).setDividerDrawable(drawable);
    }

    mTabLayout.addTab(tabHome);
    mTabLayout.addTab(tabEmprestimos);
    mTabLayout.addTab(tabPersonal);
    mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
}
```

Comment: where is your xml? expected output if you can add

Comment: Actually its pretty simple i'll add it to the question

Comment: *but each tab have some margin inside* you want to add that line inside the tabs or just below the tab buttons ?

Comment: Should be exactly like the image above. I'm really struggling with it

Comment: still didn't get that xoxo . I see the green selector below that there is nothing no :[

Comment: You know the gray line on the green line side? That's what I need. The green line should move on top of it. Sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135768/discussion-between-felipe-castilhos-and-charu).

Comment: Hi, I just need that bottom horizontal line. Not that vertical divider lines. And i am using transparent background. How can i acheive the bottom line effect ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your Drawable folder create an xml

background.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="-10dp" android:right="-10dp" android:left="-10dp">
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#1bd4f6" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#0288D1" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Set this to your `TabLayout`

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"/>
```

Change values and colors as you need!

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Felipe Castilhos did you check this?

Comment: Clearly I was wrong trying to set the background on the tab instead of the tablayout itself.

Comment: @Felipe Castilhos im glad it helped :) if you want the other edges you can remove minus values! good luck

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. The solution

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       app:tabBackground="@color/white"
       app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
       app:tabIndicatorHeight="2.5dp"
       app:tabTextColor="@color/white"/>

    <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="2.5dp"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:background="#c6c6c6" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I did it, will show the grey line over the TabLayoutSelector. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: I needed to have a tab layout selector with a fixed width and bottom border. To achieve that you can make `<View` as the top child in `FrameLayout` and set transparent background to tab layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your Drawable folder create an xml

background_line.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="-6dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp"

        >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#fff" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_15sdp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Set this to your TabLayout

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
             android:id="@+id/tabs"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/_40ssp"
             app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"

            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/background_line"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"

            app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabBackground="@color/bg_app"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            />
```

output >>>

[image]